# Environment Variables ERROR

Tags: java, windows, environment-variables

I have the code above in my application:

```
String home = System.getenv ("HOME");
System.out.println ("home directory is " + home);
```

When I am using the console (cygwin) the print is :

> home directory is C:\cygwin64\home\Tiago

But when just click on the executable I get a different path that doesnt work:

> home directory is C:\cygwin64\home\Tiago\allnet\home\Tiago

Someone can help with that?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `System.getProperty("user.home")`? Also, what executable?

Comment: I am sure. This application was created to Linux, and now I'm trying to run it on Windows. 
When I use the cygwin to run it takes the correct ENV, but when I try to run it without the cygwin (only by clicking the .exe file), it picks up the different ENV and doesnt work.

Comment: Correct. Because cygwin is more than an executable. **What** .exe file? Linux doesn't use .exe files.

Comment: I've generated a file .exe to start my application on Windows

Comment: Can you post that code? How did you generate the exe file? Have you tried a bat file?